# How do I delete all these duplicated icons at the bottom of Eclipse? I've done some googling and can't seem to find an answer

Tags: eclipse

[image]

These duplicated icon groups at the bottom keep growing and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: Reinstal :) i know that it isn't right solution but if you don't know how to remove it try to reinstal eclipse

Comment: Add more details. Which eclipse package, which version you downloaded? Your OS?How you are running eclipse?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by simply re-installing eclipse.  Simple solution, not sure why I didn't think of this sooner.  Thanks all!